# Return values not present in a table, but present on other tables SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three table Apple, Orange, Cherry.

```
In Apple I have columns: ApId, Name, BId
In Orange I have columns: ApId, OId
In Cherry I have columns: OId, CId, che
```

When I specify a condition in table Cherry which returns null (WHERE che IS NULL) on an ID OId, no records are shown in table Cherry.

How can I write an SQL query to return me the Names from table Apple when I specify the BId also?

Comment: Have one single fruit table instead.

Comment: These arbitrary names are confusing. Can you use a better example?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please add the tag for the database you are really using.  Also, sample data and desired results would really help convey what you want to do.

Comment: SQL Server.. When I specify two conditions, it will return me NULL. Please help.

Comment: post initial and final output table

Comment: Post your required  output by editing the question

Answer (score 0):

> How can I write an SQL query to return me the Names from table Apple
>   when I specify the BId also?

Do a `JOIN` among the table like

```
select a.Name
from Apple a 
join Orange o on a.ApId = o.ApId
where a.BId = BIdValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
select a.Name , o.OId
from Apple a 
join Orange o on a.ApId = o.ApId
where a.BId = BIdValue;
```